# SQL Server : Cannot roll back ...No transaction or savepoint of that name was found

Tags: sql-server, transactions

We have Perl script that bcp's data for various entities to stage tables , and then invokes a stored procedure via DBI(Autocommit=0) to move data from Stage-Core tables for these entities.

The stored procedure pseudo code is as below

```
   -- GET DETAILS from stage to temproaray tables
  SELECT * FROM <MAIN_STG_TBL> INTO  #MAIN_TBL
  SELECT * FROM <SUPP_STG_1> INTO  #supp_1
  SELECT * FROM <SUPP_STG_2> INTO  #supp_2
  .....
  SELECT * FROM <SUPP_STG_10> INTO  #supp_10


  RAISERROR (<INFO_MSG>, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT

  -- for each entity in #MAIN_TBL
  -- move datae from stage to core
  WHILE_LOOP ( EACH <ENTRY> in #MAIN_TBL )

    BEGIN TRY

     BEGIN TRAN STG_CORE

        INSERT INTO <MAIN_CORE> SELECT * FROM #MAIN_TBL WHERE ENTITY=<ENTRY>
        INSERT INTO <SUPP_CORE_1> SELECT * FROM #supp_1 WHERE ENTITY=<ENTRY>
        INSERT INTO <SUPP_CORE_1> SELECT * FROM #supp_2 WHERE ENTITY=<ENTRY>
           .....
        INSERT INTO <SUPP_CORE_10> SELECT * FROM #supp_10 WHERE ENTITY=<ENTRY>

     COMMIT TRAN STG_CORE;
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
      ROLLBACK TRAN STG_CORE;
    END CATCH

    RAISERROR (<INFO_MSG>, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT

  END LOOP

RAISERROR (<INFO_MSG>, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT
```

The stored procedure itself is invoked in a `AutoCommit=0` connection , and is immediately followed with `DBI->commit`

**ISSUE**

For all failed entities 200/1000 entities mostly due to `Primary Key Violation in some of the SUPP Tables` seeing the message `STAGE_TO_CORE_SP text=Cannot roll back STG_CORE. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found`

Comment: You should start your transaction before the TRY. The name is out of scope in the catch.

Comment: Had initially tried having `BEGIN TRAN STG_CORE` before `BEGIN TRY` , but observed similar errors.

Comment: There really is no need to name your transaction anyway. Just remove the name.

Comment: Removed transaction name , now on the perl script it fails with `Invalid object name #MAIN_TBL` for just two entities, Interestingly on toad it goes through fine. wondering if it' due to `autocommit=0` on the script ?

Comment: I can't help you with perl or toad.